# Optimization of TSQL CTE Recursion Query

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, recursion, ssms

I have the following CTE that uses recursion to fetch the level of each node in the Hierarhcy and in the end, since I have 27 levels, I am grabbing the name of each of level since the final user is not interested in seeing GUIDs.

```
    with EmpTree

    as
    (
      select e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid, cast(cast(e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid as binary(4)) as varbinary(max)) as EmpHier,
      1 as EmployeeLevel

      from [DWH].[Dim_TFS_File_View] as e
      where e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid is null 
      union all
      select c.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid, cast(p.EmpHier + cast(c.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid as binary(4)) as varbinary(max)),
      EmployeeLevel +1 as EmployeeLevel
      from EmpTree as p
      join [DWH].[Dim_TFS_File_View] as c
        on c.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
    )

    select TOP 100 PERCENT DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
         ,EmployeeLevel
         ,(SELECT [File_Name] from [DWH].[Dim_TFS_File_View] as pu where nullif(cast(substring(EmpHier, 1, 4) as int), 0) = pu.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid) level1
         ,(SELECT [File_Name] from [DWH].[Dim_TFS_File_View] as pu where nullif(cast(substring(EmpHier, 1, 9) as int), 0) = pu.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid) level2
         ,(SELECT [File_Name] from [DWH].[Dim_TFS_File_View] as pu where nullif(cast(substring(EmpHier, 1, 13) as int), 0) = pu.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid) level3
from EmpTree
order by DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
```

I have 27 levels...
The View I am grabbing info has three indexes:
(parent,child)
(parent)
(child)

This table has 200M rows and growing.. So this query is extremely slow, I think most of it also cause of all the "name grabbing" per level...

Is it a more efficient way to achieve my result? Maybe through some joins?

Please help if you can

Thanks!!

**Not Getting the proper recursions, only fetching Anchor section.**

```
with EmpTree

as
(
  select e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid,e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid,
  1 as Depth,
  File_Name_String = CAST(CAST(e.File_Name AS BINARY(100)) AS VARBINARY(8000))

  from [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] as e
  where e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid is null 
  union all
  select e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid,e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid,
  p.Depth +1 as Depth,
  File_Name_String = CAST(CONCAT(p.File_Name_String, CAST(e.File_Name AS BINARY(100))) AS VARBINARY(8000))
  from [dbo].[Hierarchy_Luis] as e 
  join EmpTree as p
    on e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
)

SELECT
        p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid,
        p.Depth,
      Level01 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level02 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   101, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level03 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   201, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level04 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   301, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level05 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   401, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level07 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   501, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level08 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   601, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level09 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   701, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level10 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   801, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level11 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   901, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level12 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1001, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level13 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1101, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level14 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1201, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level15 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1301, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level16 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1401, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level17 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1501, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level18 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1601, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level19 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1701, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level20 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1801, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level21 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   1901, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level22 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   2001, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level23 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   2101, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level24 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   2201, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level25 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   2301, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level26 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   2401, 100) as nvarchar(100)),
      Level27 =CAST(SUBSTRING(p.File_Name_String,   2501, 100) as nvarchar(100))

    FROM EmpTree p
```

Comment: You are going to have to give some sample data and expected output. Joining on a conditional substrings seems sketchy to me... but then again you are casting to binary and then varbinary(max) so it's hard to understand what you are really doing...

Comment: First thing... BINARY(4) isn't big enough to hold a GUID... So you're likely to get bad data from this... **CAST(CAST(e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid AS BINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS EmpHier**. As for performance, I'd have to assume the 3 correlated subqueries are the real bottleneck here but we'll need usable test data to verify.

Comment: Looking closer at the code... There is no need for the correlated sub-queries. You can simply add File_Name to the recursive CTE.

Comment: CTE's perform horribly with deep recursion and large data sets. You might even be better off using a straight up loop instead so it doesn't have to cache all that data in a single go.

Comment: Jason you are right, but these are not normal guids, but it is the name they gave on the database.
Also, I can get the File_Name in the recursion, but then I still have to make those 27 columns and maybe add a column with the whole path separated by "/" and then for each level use like a substring function to identify the name of each level ?

Comment: In that case, please post the actual data types. It sounds like Dim_TFS_File_View is an indexed view, so that's good, but we can't help unless we know the data types you're working with.

Comment: But just a question, if i bring the name in the recursion, the split per level would have to involve some work with substring and charindex and stuff like thar correct?

Comment: Negligible at best... especially when compared to what you're doing now.

Comment: I just posted an answer based on what I think you're trying to do. Have a look and see if it's in the ballpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having representative test data and expected outcome, it's difficult to nail down the specifics... The following should be in the ball part though...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dim_TFS_File_View', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Dim_TFS_File_View;
GO 
CREATE TABLE #Dim_TFS_File_View (
    DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid INT NOT NULL,
    DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid INT NULL,
    [File_Name] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Dim_TFS_File_View (DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid, DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid, [File_Name])
SELECT 
    DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid = t.n,
    DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = CASE WHEN t.n = 1 THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(NULLIF(mi.ManagerID -1, 0), 1) END,
    [File_Name] = NEWID()
FROM 
    dbo.tfn_Tally(1000, 1) t
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % t.n + 1) ) mi (ManagerID);

-- SELECT * FROM #Dim_TFS_File_View dtfv;

WITH 
    cte_Recursion AS (
        SELECT 
            e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid,
            NodeLevel = 1,
            File_Name_String = CAST(CAST(e.[File_Name] AS BINARY(16)) AS VARBINARY(8000))
        FROM 
            #Dim_TFS_File_View e
        WHERE 
            e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid IS NULL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid,
            NodeLevel = r.NodeLevel + 1,
            File_Name_String = CAST(CONCAT(r.File_Name_String, CAST(e.[File_Name] AS BINARY(16))) AS VARBINARY(8000))
        FROM 
            cte_Recursion r
            JOIN #Dim_TFS_File_View e
                ON r.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid = e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid
        )
SELECT
    r.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid,
    r.NodeLevel,
    Level01 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String,   1, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level02 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String,  17, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level03 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String,  33, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level04 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String,  49, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level05 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String,  65, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level06 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String,  81, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level07 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String,  97, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level08 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 113, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level09 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 129, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level10 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 145, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level11 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 161, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level12 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 177, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level13 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 193, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level14 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 209, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level15 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 225, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level16 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 241, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level17 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 257, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level18 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 273, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level19 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 289, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level20 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 305, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level21 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 321, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level22 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 337, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level23 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 353, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level24 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 369, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level25 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 385, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level26 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 401, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    Level27 = NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(r.File_Name_String, 417, 16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
FROM
    cte_Recursion r;
```

A sample of the output...

```
DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid NodeLevel   Level01                              Level02                              Level03                              Level04                              Level05                              Level06                              Level07                              Level08                              Level09                              Level10                              Level11                              Level12                              Level13                              Level14                              Level15                              Level16                              Level17                              Level18                              Level19                              Level20                              Level21                              Level22                              Level23                              Level24                              Level25                              Level26                              Level27
------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
1                              1           F7CCFA67-F558-41EE-B1BF-8D96692AB99F NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL
2                              2           F7CCFA67-F558-41EE-B1BF-8D96692AB99F 34CAF6D3-44BA-4DE1-9E03-836EE38C43E3 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL
3                              2           F7CCFA67-F558-41EE-B1BF-8D96692AB99F A69D9BE6-D83A-40AB-9D5B-04219317A3F9 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL                                 NULL
```

Comment: You are a fking boss!
This solution works as well, didnt check performance, but from the small test I made the results were faster.
Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: And yeah, I realized I kind of had the solution all along.. Thanks for taking this roadblock from my head!

Comment: Nice! I'm glad that was able to help.